# Dataweave 2.0 : how to assign else block data to variable

Tags: function, variables, dataweave, mule4

I'm using external dwl file which has if-else block in side a function. The output of function will become payload, but how to get 'IF' block valid data in to one variable and 'ELSE' block invalid data in to another variable, so that I use these two variables to write into two separate files, one has success records, and another has failed records.

**Runtime: 4.2.1**

```
fun providerObjMapping(payload) = (if(! isEmpty(payload.ProviderUniqueID)) {

  providerUniqueID:   payload.ProviderUniqueID,
  salutation:payload.Salutation,
  firstName:payload.FirstName,
  middleName:payload.MiddleName,
  lastName:payload.LastName 
        
} else {
errorProviderUniqueID:   payload.ProviderUniqueID,
errorSalutation:payload.Salutation,
errorFirstName:payload.FirstName,
errorMiddleName:payload.MiddleName,
errorLastName:payload.LastName
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible from inside DataWeave. By design each component in a Mule 4 flow can return a value that can be assigned to the OR to ONE variable.

Use a Choice router to perform different assignments.

Answer (score 0):

@aled is correct; you can do it using a `Choice` processor if you are interested in only the success or failures.

If on the other hand you need both at the same time then you can use a `Transform Message` processor and add another target that stores the transformation in a variable.  Here's the [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.1/transform-add-another-output-transform-studio-task).

Here's what the `Transform Message` should look like:

```
        <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="4a9eae14-79e8-4ef3-acec-00901f548e00" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="valid" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun providerObjMapping(payload) = if (! isEmpty(payload.ProviderUniqueID) ) {
    providerUniqueID:   payload.ProviderUniqueID,
    salutation:payload.Salutation,
    firstName:payload.FirstName,
    middleName:payload.MiddleName,
    lastName:payload.LastName       
} else {
    errorProviderUniqueID:   payload.ProviderUniqueID,
    errorSalutation:payload.Salutation,
    errorFirstName:payload.FirstName,
    errorMiddleName:payload.MiddleName,
    errorLastName:payload.LastName
}

---
providerObjMapping(payload)]]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="invalid" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun providerObjMapping(payload) = if ( isEmpty(payload.ProviderUniqueID) ) {
    providerUniqueID:   payload.ProviderUniqueID,
    salutation:payload.Salutation,
    firstName:payload.FirstName,
    middleName:payload.MiddleName,
    lastName:payload.LastName       
} else {
    errorProviderUniqueID:   payload.ProviderUniqueID,
    errorSalutation:payload.Salutation,
    errorFirstName:payload.FirstName,
    errorMiddleName:payload.MiddleName,
    errorLastName:payload.LastName
}

---
providerObjMapping(payload)]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
```

Comment: I may get 1 million records in a batch file, with the above approach I've to process same file twice. Is there any optimized way